# SaxonHE XQuery sum operation precision

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon

I have a such xml document

```
<root>
  <a>20947441.21</a>
  <b>9961900</b>
  <c>27360153.6</c>
  <d>222864.95</d>
  <e>10489146.31</e>
</root>
```

and I need to get a sum of root's child elements. So execute the following xquery expression using SaxonHE processor (v 10.5):

```
let $s := (/root/a, /root/b, /root/c, /root/d, /root/e), $res := sum($s) return $res
```

The result of the expression is `6.898150607000001E7`. Why it is not `68981506.07`? How I cant get the predictable result without scientific notation and with proper precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `xs:decimal` datatype instead of the default number/xs:double by selecting simply `sum(root/*/xs:decimal(.))` or, in the context of your sample, `sum($s ! xs:decimal(.))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [format-number](https://www.altova.com/xpath-xquery-reference/fn-format-number) function:

```
return format-number($res, '#.00')
```

And you can possibly simplify your expression to select all direct children of  `root`:

```
let $s := (/root/*), $res := sum($s) return format-number($res, '#.00')
```

Or even

```
let $res := sum(/root/*) return format-number($res, '#.00')
```