# SaxonHE: How to use XSD types on XQuery execution

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery, saxon

I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="example.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a>0.1</a>
    <b>0.2</b>
</root>
```

which is associated with the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="a" type="xs:decimal"/>
                <xs:element name="b" type="xs:decimal"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Using this code snippet I execute an XQuery expression `let $a := /root/a, $b := /root/b, $res := $a + $b return $res`:

```
var proc = new Processor(false);

var builder = proc.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.setBaseURI(URI.create("http://test.ru"));

var file = new File(filePath);
var doc = builder.build(file);

var expression = "let $a := /root/a, $b := /root/b, $res := $a + $b return $res";

var compiler = proc.newXQueryCompiler();
var executable = compiler.compile(expression);
var selector = executable.load();
selector.setContextItem(doc);

return selector.evaluate();
```

The result is `0.30000000000000004`. According this question ([SaxonHE XQuery sum operation precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69025678/saxonhe-xquery-sum-operation-precision)) it is because of the default `number/xs:double` type.

However, I have an XSD in which elements `a` and `b` have `xs:decimal` type. It there are any way to tell Saxon use types from XSD on XQuery expression executions?

**UPDATE**

I've got a trial license for SaxonEE and pass the license using the following code:

```
var conf = new com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseConfiguration();
conf.setConfigurationProperty(Feature.LICENSE_FILE_LOCATION, "/path/to/saxon-license.lic");

var proc = new Processor(conf);
```

I use the same xml document and xsd. In prolog of xquery expression I've added an `import schema`:

```
import schema default element namespace "" at "/path/to/example.xsd";
let $a := /root/a, $b := /root/b, $res := $a + $b return $res
```

But I still have `0.30000000000000004` as a result. What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

According to all suggestions here is the working example of schema-aware XQuery using Saxon-EE:

```
var conf = new com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseConfiguration();
conf.setConfigurationProperty(Feature.LICENSE_FILE_LOCATION, "/path/to/saxon-license.lic");
conf.setSchemaValidationMode(net.sf.saxon.lib.Validation.STRICT);

var proc = new Processor(conf);

var schemaManager = proc.getSchemaManager();
var source = new SAXSource(new InputSource("/path/to/example.xsd"));
schemaManager.load(source);

var builder = proc.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.setBaseURI(URI.create("http://test.ru"));

var file = new File(filePath);
var doc = builder.build(file);

var prolog = "import schema default element namespace "" at "/path/to/example.xsd";"
var expression = prolog + "let $a := /root/a, $b := /root/b, $res := $a + $b return $res";

var compiler = proc.newXQueryCompiler();
var executable = compiler.compile(expression);
var selector = executable.load();
selector.setContextItem(doc);

return selector.evaluate();
```

Comment: If you add two decimals, how can the result be less than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to switch to Saxon EE then you can of course use schema-aware XQuery with e.g. https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-schema-import and the schema will be used and your values will be `xs:decimal`s. Or with the right settings the document might be parsed and validated based on the schemaLocation attribute (https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/schema-processing/saqueryapi.html).

Even in HE, however, nothing prevents you from doing `let $a := xs:decimal(/root/a), $b := xs:decimal(/root/b)`, you might need to declare the namespace in the query prolog.

Comment: I've update my question. In some reasons this answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Dmitriy, I think you first need to set `https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/Validation.html#STRICT` e.g. `proc.getUnderlyingConfiguration(). setSchemaValidationMode(net.sf.saxon.lib.Validation.STRICT);` or `conf.setSchemaValidationMode(net.sf.saxon.lib.Validation.STRICT)`.

Comment: Thank you, sounds reasonable. But with this `STRICT` mode I've got an `Cannot validate <Q{}root>: no element declaration available` error on xml document building.

Comment: I am not set up here to do schema-aware XQuery from Saxon and Java so let's hope Michael Kay reads your question or ask in the Saxonica forum itself, once you have looked through the samples from the documentation (I think they explicitly set a Validator on the DocumentBuilder) and perhaps first ensured that your XML/XSD/XQuery works from the Saxon command line as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the tip - obtain a proper result. I've updated my question with the final example.